# GridView on item click listener

Tags: java, android, gridview

```
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(ScenesActivity.this, position + "#Selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScenesDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(TestConstants.SELCTED_SCENE_KEY, position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
```

TestConstants.java

```
public interface TestConstants {

 String SELCTED_SCENE_KEY="SELCTED_SCENE"; }
```

I want to get ScenesDetailActivity after click the slected scene key.  It seems that the above code doesn't work as expected. Can someone help me to slove it? Thanks a lot! Simonides

Comment: What isn't working? The next view is not displayed? Are you sending the data you need to detail? You're only sending an index position.

Comment: Post your gridView item xml file if onItemClick is not getting fired or post the details of the logcat if your are getting any exceptions

Comment: expand your question please

Comment: After click first item in GridView I want to see ScenesDetailActivity. Now nothing happens when I click on item.

Answer (score 7):

does the gridView have a custom layout ?

if yes, go to the custom layout xml file and change these attributes

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the cleanest way to do it: call performItemClick() on the GridView from within each button's click listener in your Adapter. That way you can still use the GridView's onItemClickListener like normal.

```
// in your ListAdapter
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    // set btn to be your item's view
    ...

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((GridView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

From http://www.migapro.com/click-events-listview-gridview/