# Android click on Button to display all installed app on screen

Tags: android, screen, installed-applications

In my app i want like this :

User click on Button -> display all installed app with their icon (as we get in mobile screen in same index) on screen.

when click on installed app icon open specific click application.

any one giving me any idea or demo to how to do this ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of all installed apps like this :

```
 final List<ApplicationInfo> pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for(ApplicationInfo app : pkgAppsList)
  {
          // here you will get all the properties of the app

           // Launch app
          Intent i=   getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);
          startActivity(i);
   }
```

Comment: how to get app icon ?

Comment: `app.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager())`

Comment: in this, possible to open particular application as click on application named-icon ? click on camera , open camera like this.

Comment: `getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);`

Comment: on line 3 : it giving type miss-match , can not convert to List<Resolveinfo> to List<ApplicationInfo>

Comment: i got **null** all time in **getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);**

Comment: Can you please google for such errors??? Keep in your mind : SO is not for spoon-feeding, we can just show you the way,can't code for you everytime..

Comment: I am not getting it **null** .. `Intent i =  getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);
                       Log.e("Intent ",i.toString())` Check it

Comment: i used gridview to display app-icon it display well ,but when i click on onItemClick of gridview **at that time** how to know clickable app package to launch application ?

Comment: [check it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918633/gridview-on-item-click-listener) please [join this for more query....](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13436/smart-developers-lab)